# How to connect a socket to another computer's socket through Internet

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I recently have some difficulties to connect a socket to another computer's socket through Internet, an image is worth a thousand words:

[image]

Computer **A** is running this "**listener.py**" script:

```
import socket
PORT = 50007              
BUFFER = 2048              
HOST = ''  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen(1)
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(BUFFER)
                if not data: break
                conn.sendall(data)
```

Computer **B** is running this "**sender.py**" script:

```
import socket
HOST = '101.81.83.169'    # The remote host
PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
        s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
```

So first of all, I run the "**listener**" script of the computer **A**. Then, I run the "**sender**" script of the computer B. However, when I execute the "**sender**" script, I received a **error** message which explains me that I am not authorized to connect to this remote address.

So I would like to know how can I connect a socket to another socket through internet without changing the router configurations.

Thank you very much for your help.

**Edit**: Here the error message (I didn't execute the same script for some reasons, but it's the same error message)

```
sock.connect(('101.81.83.169',50007)) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in
 <module>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in
meth     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Comment: What error message is seen in `sender.py`?

Comment: 'I receive an error message which explains [to] me that I am not authorized to connect to this remote address'. No you don't. You get an error message. Don't interpret, paraphrase, mangle. Tell us the *exact*, *actual* error message. *We* will tell *you* what it means. In this case 'connection refused' has exactly one meaning: nothing is listening at the IP:port you specified. Nothing to do with authorization whatsoever.

Comment: @EJP: "Connection refused" does not always mean a port is not listening (in this case, it does).  It could also mean the port is listening, but its backlog of pending connections is full at the moment.  It could also mean an intermediate firewall has blocked the connection before it reached the listening port.  "Connection refused" simply means exactly that - the connection was refused, but the client won't know WHY it was refused.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It always means exactly that except for one specific brand of router/firewall that was being shipped *circa* 2000, before it was realized that leaking negative information is still an information leak.

Comment: @EJP: "Connection refused" does not *always* mean firewall blockage. As I said earlier, it also happens when "*the port is listening, but its backlog of pending connections is full at the moment*". That is the same OS response that is used when the port is not open for listening at all. So again, the client does not know WHY the connection is being refused, it could be for several different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Computer B can't directly connect to computer A since it has an IP address which is not reachable from the outside.  You need to set up a port forwarding rule in the 101.81.83.169 router that redirects incoming connection requests for port 50007 to IP address 192.168.0.4.

However, since you say that you are seeking a solution without changing router configurations, you need something different.

In this case, you could setup an intermediate server running on the public Internet that both computers can then connect to and serves as an intermediate tunneling platform between them. Solutions for this already exist, for example have a look at [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), which has Python bindings available.

Comment: He isn't trying to connect to system B. He is trying to connect to system A, via its public IP address. Read the question.

Comment: @EJP - It does not matter, both systems are identical regarding their accessibility. And system A does not have a public IP address, the default gateway router that system A uses has a public IP address. Same for B. My answer still stands.

Comment: Your answer starts with 'you can't directly connect to system B' which has nothing to do with the question that was asked. You could always fix it.

Answer (score 0):

> So I would like to know how can I connect a socket to another socket through internet without changing the router configurations.

You can't. The public IP address belongs to your router. Your server isn't listening in the router, it is listening in some host behind the router. You have to open that port in your router and forward it to the host your listener is running in: whatever that means in your particular router. Otherwise the router will refuse the connection, as it doesn't have anything listening at that port.

Comment: If the router supports uPNP, the listener can dynamically open the port on the router and forward incoming connections to itself.  Otherwise, the router admin must configure the router's port forwarding manually.

Answer (score 0):

From the book ["Computer Networking: A Top-Down Approach"](http://www.nylxs.com/docs/cmpnet.pdf), there is a part which is very interesting on page 149 about how Bittorents work:

> Each torrent has an infrastructure node called a tracker. When a peer joins a torrent, it registers itself with the tracker and periodically informs the tracker that it is still in the torrent. In this manner, the tracker keeps track of the peers that are participating in the torrent. A given torrent may have fewer than ten or more than a thousand peers participating at any instant of time. **Alice, joins** the torrent, the tracker randomly selects a subset of peers (for concreteness, say 50) from the set of participating peers, and **sends the IP addresses** of these 50 peers to Alice. Possessing this list of peers, Alice attempts **to establish concurrent TCP connections with all the peers on this list**. Let’s call all the peers with which Alice succeeds in establishing a TCP connection “neighboring peers.

[image]

So:

**- Step 1**: Alice connects to the tracker, the tracker gives to Alice the ip addresses of Bob and Mick.

**- Step 2**:Alice receives the ip addresses of Bob and Mick, then she can try to establish TCP/IP connections for downloading the file.

I don't remember having to set up any router configuration when I wanted to download files from Bittorent.

So what am I missing?

Comment: A question is not an answer, and there is no evidence here that you succeeded in connecting to any other host behind a router whose ports weren't opened and forwarded.

Comment: If you really want to know how BitTorrent peers connect to each other through routers, read the various [BitTorrent protocol specifications](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0000.html).  Also see [Why does bittorrent not require port forwarding?](http://superuser.com/questions/952061/).