# How do I connect two machines (with two different public IPs) via sockets using Python? Is it possible?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, heroku, ip-address

I'm new to the world of networking and wanted to clarify some of my thoughts regarding a problem I am facing at the moment. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631360/how-to-connect-a-socket-to-another-computers-socket-through-internet) post which makes me think what I'm doing may be impossible, but I thought it would be worth a shot to ask on here and see what more qualified people think about it.

I am a TA for an intro computer science course, and I am writing a final project for students to complete at the end of the semester. Essentially, the project would be to fill in the holes in the implementation of a messaging client. I have set it up so each client would run two threads (one to listen for incoming messages, and one to wait for input to send messages to the other client). I have gotten this to work successfully on localhost with communication between two different port numbers, and am trying to find a way to have this work over the network so the two clients do not necessarily have to be on the same machine.

After struggling through a few methods, I came up with this solution: I would host a server on Heroku that would keep track of the clients' IPs and port numbers, and use a rest API so that one client could easily get the IP and port of the other client they are trying to communicate with. I have tested this, and the API seems to work. Thus, a client can create a socket endpoint and send it to this server to be entered into its database, and when the communication is terminated, it is removed from the database (this JSON would store a username as the primary key and internally manage an IP and port number) as the connection is now closed.

So, what I have is each client with an IP and port number knowing the IP and port number it is trying to communicate with. My last struggle is to actually form the connection. I understand there is a distinction between localhost (127.0.0.1) and the public IP for an internet endpoint. Upon searching, I found a way to find the public IP for the current user to share with the database, but *I cannot bind to it*. Whenever I try to, I get sockets **error code 13: permission denied**. I would imagine that if I tried connecting to the public IP of the other machine, I would get a similar error (but I cannot test the client until I can get a server running!).

I read online that some router work would be needed to actually form this connection between two machines. I guess I'm struggling to understand the practicality of socket programming if such a simple operation (connecting two socket endpoints on two different computers) requires so much tweaking. Is there something I am missing?

For reference, here is a general outline of my code thus far. The server:

```
# Server thread
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((LOCAL_IP, AVAILABLE_PORT))
s.listen(1)

# In my code, there is a quitting mechanism which closes s as well.
while True:
    client_socket, addr = s.accept()
    data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print "Received: " + data
    client_socket.close()
```

...and the client:

```
# Client thread 
# It is an infinite loop so I am always waiting for another potential message to send
while True:
    x = raw_input()
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((OTHER_MACHINE_LOCAL_IP, OTHER_PORT))
    sock.sendall(x)
    sock.close()
```

Right now, I cannot make progress with these *permission denied* errors. Is there any way I could get this to work? Understand that, being that this would be for around 250ish students to use who are all intro CS students, I would want to avoid having to instruct them to do anything with their routers.

*If there is another method to do this which would make this easier that I am missing, I would also love to hear any suggestions :)* Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you on Windows? This could be a firewall denying the bind. In that case you can write a rule for the port (if it is well known) or the application that lets it through. You will still have problems if you are on a private network (and 99% of the time, you are on a private network) because a machine's locally-known IPv4 address is not visible on the internet.

Comment: Some systems restrict low range IP port numbers but let high ones through. Try something like 55555. You could do a bind with a 0 port number and let the system choose one for you. So, before a `listen` do `somesocket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 0))` followed by by `addr, port = somesocket.getsockname()`.

Comment: @tdelaney I am on a Mac computer. If I am on a private network (and assuming most students who would want to chat on this network are), is my current method not possible using this socket method?

Comment: The challenge is that Heroku server. I assume its running on the internet. I am on a private network and my IPv4 address is `192.168.0.7`. There are 10s of thousands of people on private networks with the same address. As long as everyone I want to chat with is on my private network, then I can register `192.168.0.7` on your Heroku server and it will work. But if they go home at night, no such luck. Its fine as a learning tool while everyone is on campus. But that's the limit.